# Place Outbound Twilio Call and Respond to User Input

Tags: twilio-api

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I am developing an MVC application that generates an outbound call from a web page.  What I want to do is to allow the recipient of the phone call to be able to make DTMF selections on their keypad.  I know there are methods within Twilio to respond to DTMF input for inbound calls, using the  verb but I don't see any documentation for outbound calls and wonder if it can even be accomplished. When the outbound call is answered I created a simple web form that is called:

```
    Dim header As String = "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "?>"
    Dim message As String = "<Response>"
    message = message & "<Gather>"

    message = message & "<Play loop=" & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & ">http://www.mydomain/Sounds/Call.wav</Play>"

    message = message & "</Gather>"

    message = message & "</Response>"

    Response.ClearContent()

    Response.Clear()

    Response.Write(header & message)
```

which in turn generates a TwiML response:

http://www.mydomain/Sounds/Call.wav

So once the user presses 1 is where I am confused as to what to do.  I did come across the article Respond to Incoming Phone Calls in C#

that speaks to responding to user input.  I tried:

Dim response = New VoiceResponse()
response.Gather(New Gather(numDigits:=1, action:="/voice/gather"))

but am receiving a syntax error on the second line, even though I think it is the VB.Net equivalent C# version 5.x example.  So it really seems like I should be able to accomplish my task, but I am stuck as to how to get his working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 would be to setup an endpoint to handle inbound calls as outlined in the documentation.

Step 2 is then to setup an a function to place outbound calls and the url param of the `client.calls.create()` function will be the endpoint from step 1.